# Instantiation of object in Vala generic

Tags: vala

I want to create a new object of given type inside of generic in Vala language.

```
class MyClass <T> : GLib.Object
{
    protected T data;

    public MyClass ()
    {
        data = new T ();
    }
}
```

I understand that this can't work, but what is the way to do something like that?

Comment: Have you looked at using [Object.new](https://valadoc.org/gobject-2.0/GLib.Object.@new.html) with a [Type](https://valadoc.org/gobject-2.0/GLib.Type.html)? Not sure what your trying to do really

Comment: Yes, this is a good direction to seach the solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably best instantiating it when calling the constructor for `MyClass`:

```
void main () {
    new MyClass<Test> (new Test ());
    new MyClass<Example> (new Example ());
}

class MyClass <T>
{
    protected T data;

    public MyClass (T data)
        {
            this.data = data;
        }
}

class Test {}

class Example {}
```

Vala generics do not currently provide constraints. If you are going to pass in a dependency in this way you may want to consider using an interface type instead of a generic type.

#### Update

If you are wanting to implement a factory then an interface with a static method or function is probably best:

```
void main () {
    var a = CommandFactory.get_command ("A");
    var b = CommandFactory.get_command ("B");

    a.run ();
    b.run ();
}

namespace CommandFactory {
    Command get_command (string criteria) {
        Command result = null;
        switch (criteria) {
            case "A":
                result = new CommandA ();
                break;
            case "B":
                result = new CommandB ();
                break;
            default:
                assert_not_reached ();
        }
        return result;
    }
}

interface Command:Object {
    public abstract void run ();
}

class CommandA:Object, Command {
    void run () { print ("A\n"); }
}

class CommandB:Object, Command {
    void run () { print ("B\n"); }
}
```

I assume by 'abstract fabric pattern' you mean 'abstract factory pattern'? You could try using GType introspection to then instantiate the Object, but it must be a GObject and you by pass Vala's static analysis checks:

```
void main () {
    new MyClass<Example> (new Example ());

    /* These will fail at runtime
    new MyClass<string> ("this will fail at runtime");
    new MyClass<ThisWillFailAtRuntime> (new ThisWillFailAtRuntime ());
    */
}

class MyClass <T>
{
    protected T data;

    public MyClass (T data)
        {
            assert (typeof(T).is_object());
            this.data = Object.new (typeof(T));
        }
}

class Example:Object {}

class ThisWillFailAtRuntime {}
```

Note that `Object.new()` is also a static method.

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but you are probably better looking more closely at interfaces and favouring composition over inheritance in your object data model.

Comment: I need an abstract fabric pattern, so this is not a solution to instantiate object outside of generic.